# How much additional damage does the spell Firebrand do?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, damage, actions, environmental-hazards

The spell *Firebrand* (*Spell Compendium* p.93) states:

> All subjects hit by the burst in the round the spell is cast or within the area in the following round take 1d6 points of fire damage per two caster levels (maximum 5d6). A character struck in the round the spell is cast can attempt to extinguish the flames on itself as a full-round action with a successful DC 15 Reflex save

So, how much damage does Grog the Unfortunate take in these three scenarios when hit by the level 10 wizard Cosmo's *Firebrand*:

**Scenario A**:

1. Grog the Unfortunate is standing in one of *Firebrand's* blast zones and fails his reflex save and thus takes full damage from the spell's initial hit.
2. Grog the Unfortunate takes a full-round action to extinguish himself, but otherwise does not move. He passes the DC 15 reflex save.

**Scenario B**:

1. Grog the Unfortunate is standing in one of *Firebrand's* blast zones and fails his reflex save and thus takes full damage from the spell's initial hit.
2. Grog the Unfortunate just stands there for a full round confused about his life choices, and thus takes full burn damage.

**Scenario C**:

1. Grog the Unfortunate is standing in one of *Firebrand's* blast zones and fails his reflex save and thus takes full damage from the spell's initial hit.
2. Grog the Unfortunate decides to be less unfortunate and moves out of the blast zone with a 5-foot step. He then takes a full-round action to extinguish himself and succeeds on the DC 15 reflex save.

In all three scenarios, Grog starts out taking 10d6 damage. But then for each scenario, does he take an additional 0 fire damage, 10d6 fire damage, or 5d6 fire damage? Things to consider are:

1. When does the burn damage happen?
2. Does taking a full-round action to receive a reflex save actually help anything, or has he taken every possible bit of burn damage already by the time the spell is complete?
3. Can the burn damage happen twice (once on hit, once if standing in the patch on the following round)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the person who marked down this question would let me know why you marked it down, I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that readers can follow this more easily, I'm taking the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell *firebrand* [evoc] (*Spell Compendium* 93) from the top of its description:

> Each [separate 1-per-caster-level 5-ft.-radius burst] deals 1d6 points of fire damage per caster level (maximum 10d6) to all creatures within the area. All subjects hit by the burst in the round the spell is cast or within the area in the following round take 1d6 points of fire damage per two caster levels (maximum 5d6). A character
>   struck in the round the spell is cast can attempt to extinguish the flames on itself as a full-round action with a successful DC 15 Reflex save.

The first sentence details what happens when the spell comes into effect initially and is relatively clear. This is to what the spell's entry *Saving Throw: Reflex half* applies to.

The second sentence is complicated by its compound nature. First, there's *All subjects hit by the burst in the round the spell is cast* then the conjunction *or* then, second, *[all subjects] within the area in the following round* then both share the predicate *take 1d6 points of fire damage per two caster levels (maximum 5d6).*

The third sentence offers an escape route to avoid extra damage for those who were present in one of the spell's areas initially. And, yes, if such victims want to avoid being dealt damage, they should *also* get out of the area!

**Scenario A** sees Cosmo on his turn cast the *firebrand* spell to deal Grog 10d6 points of fire damage. On his turn, Grog takes a full-round action to make a Reflex saving throw to "extinguish the flames" (DC 15) and succeeds. Next round at the beginning of the same initiative count on which Cosmo cast the *firebrand* spell, Grog *won't* be dealt 5d6 points of fire damage for having been in a *firebrand* spell area initially, but he *will* be dealt 5d6 points of fire damage for being in a *firebrand* spell area *now*.

**Scenario B** sees Cosmo on his turn cast the *firebrand* spell to deal Grog 10d6 points of fire damage. On his turn, Grog takes a full-round action to pose dramatically. Next round at the beginning of the same initiative count on which Cosmo cast the *firebrand* spell, Grog will be dealt 5d6 points of fire damage for having been in a *firebrand* spell area initially, *and* he *will* be dealt 5d6 points of fire damage for being in a *firebrand* spell area *now*.

**Scenario C** sees Cosmo on his turn cast the *firebrand* spell to deal Grog 10d6 points of fire damage. On his turn, Grog takes a 5-ft. step out of the area affected by the *firebrand* spell and takes a full-round action to make a Reflex saving throw to "extinguish the flames" (DC 15) and succeeds. Next round at the beginning of the same initiative count on which Cosmo cast the *firebrand* spell, Grog won't be dealt 5d6 points of fire damage for having been in a *firebrand* spell area initially, *and* he won't be dealt 5d6 points of fire damage for being in a *firebrand* spell area *now* because he exited the area.

As can be seen by the scenarios, the spell's two secondary damage-dealing effects (called *burn damage* in the question) occur 1 round after the spell's cast, taking the full-round action and succeeding on the saving throw can be useful, and both of the spell's secondary damage-dealing effects can occur to the same unfortunate soul if all he does is stand there and pose dramatically instead of exiting the area and slapping himself until the fire goes out.

---

***Note:*** For a brief, shining moment—until the release of the errata for Magic of Faerûn *(Aug. 2001)—the spell* firebrand *was the best damage-dealing spell ever. Among other changes implemented by the* Spell Compendium *when the spell was updated for the* 3.5 *revision and omitted from the original spell but included in the* Magic *errata was the line* a creature can be affected by only one burst. *This erratum prevented casters from catching Large and bigger creatures in four or more different and not overlapping* firebrand *spell bursts for a truly excessive amount of fire damage. Big monsters everywhere applauded this change.*

Comment: @WannabeWarlock I think that if you read the scenarios again and look for that timing concern that you'll find I addressed precisely when the secondary damage occurs. To be clear, the spell occurs initially right after Cosmo casts it on his turn then the spell's secondary effects occur next round on the initiative count right before Cosmo would take his turn. Does that make sense? (I think many folks use initiative cards, and if you do then this spell's complicated if Cosmo delays or whatever because the spell will still happen next round *when he cast it* and *not* when Cosmo takes his turn!)

Comment: Also, it was buried in my previous comment, but is there a time between the caster's original turn and the start of the caster's second turn where creatures can safely walk through that area without taking bonus fire damage? It seems like they only take damage if they enter a strike zone starting 1 round after it is cast. Is that correct?

Comment: @WannabeWarlock Creatures in the initial blast area and creatures that're present now in the initial blast area suffer secondary effects next round on the same initiative count right before when Cosmo typically would've gone. There *is* that weird safe period between when it's cast that allows folks to traverse the area; it doesn't have a duration so it follows its own rules. ("If the spell affects an area… then the spell stays with that area for its duration. Creatures become subject to the spell when they enter the area and are no longer subject to it when they leave" (*PH* 176).)

Comment: I don't understand why creatures hit by the blast suffer secondary effects on the next turn instead of immediately since there is no timing text given other than perhaps allowing them time to make their save, but I will take your word for it. Regarding the hazard zone, I know that starts doing damage on the next initiative count of the caster. Am I reading correctly that any creature entering that zone during that full round (until the _following_ initiative count of the caster) will take damage? It's not just the ones already in the zone when the caster's turn starts, right? Sry for confusion

Comment: @WannabeWarlock I was revisiting this, and you're right: that second sentence is a mess. Literally, it seems that a creature struck by the initial burst should be dealt Xd6 (Ref save for half) *and* ½(Xd6) (no save) then, if that creature doesn't move, it'll be dealt *another* ½(Xd6) (no save). However, that makes the whole *Put out the fire!* thing dumb except in weird edge cases where the dude can't move. Even then, I'm not sure *which* flames the spell's even talking about. I really recommend metally move *the following round* to the beginning of the second sentence for sanity.